# Is it possible to install Z3 in Visual Studio with NuGet and use it with C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, z3

The title should be clear, but just for the records, I tried installing Z3 with NuGet, but the package doesn't have the include directory or the lib file, and of course it doesn't allow C++ or C compilation. Is it possible to do it, or should I just go the CMake way?

Answer (score 0):

The package manager for Visual Studio C++ project  is Vcpkg.

[image]

In Visual Studio, right click your project -> open in terminal :

```
vcpkg install z3:x64-windows
```

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately the `vcpkg` version shipped with Visual Studio 2022 doesn't have classic mode, so I used `vcpkg add port z3`. It seemed to work, but during installation I got a strange fail during the latest step (final linking I think). In the end I went for CMake and the usual directory and input files hell. It works, but `pip install z3` is better.